# What is that linker error in my first project in iOS development (objective-C)?

Tags: ios, linker

I came across the problem below in my first project. What is that linker error? Is that between model and ViewController files?

***Apple Mach-O Linker Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ObebOkekModel", referenced from
and 
Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

I would appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means the linker can't find a class with a name like `ObebOkekModel`

In Objective-C one way this can happen is if the .m file isn't added to the target you are building. Select the file .m and view the File Inspector to make sure there is a checkmark next to the target you are building.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Mike! Problem solved. I'm one of new developer of Obj-C, it was a basic problem. I learned now!